# How to use canvas draw randomly?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, ondraw

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(10,10,10, paint);
    //canvas.drawRect(10,20,30,40, paint);
}
```

This is a simple `onDraw` function. I made `drawRect` to comment. My goal is to find a way to let this function randomly pick draw circle or rectangle. Could someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(new Random().nextInt(2)==0)
    canvas.drawCircle(10,10,10,paint);
else
    canvas.drawRectangle(10,20,30,40,paint);
```

Base your actions on a random number. nextInt(x) provides an integer smaller than x and equal or larger than zero.

I used nextInt() since it offers the flexibility of expanding to more than 2 choices if you want... then you can use the same structure with a switch() statement for example... otherwise, as st0le comments, nextBoolean() is a great choice.

Comment: I would've gone with `nextBoolean()` :)

Comment: @st0le - I was just thinking that this method is generalizable to x choices (many different shapes)

Comment: True Peter, just thought i should mention it. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is more a java question than an android question, but as long as you do not need exact accuracy (the random function is not all that random I believe), this will do:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    if (Math.random() > 0.5)
        canvas.drawCircle(10,10,10, paint);
    else
        canvas.drawRect(10,20,30,40, paint);
}
```